# c# save data from datagridview to database

Tags: c#, oledb

I would like to edit my database record from datagridview and save from there. What properties do i need to declare to enable me to edit the datagrid? And button2 is my save button, how do i update to the database? Someone please help me thanks!

```
    {
        //Get ID
        string strTagIds = string.Empty;

        //Connection to datebase
        string c1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Project.mdb";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(c1);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //button1.Click += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_CellContentClick);

        //Bind button
        string txt = textBox1.Text;

        string strOleDbConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Project.mdb";
        string strSqlStatement = string.Empty;
        strSqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM jiahe WHERE [User] = '" + txt + "'";
        OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection(strOleDbConnectionString);
        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSqlStatement, objConnection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        objAdapter.Fill(ds);

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

        try
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                string strLine = string.Empty;
                string strUser = string.Empty;

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string strTags = dr["Tag ID"].ToString();
                    strUser = dr["User"].ToString();
                    string strAge = dr["Age"].ToString();
                    string strPhoneNumber = dr["Phone Number"].ToString();

                    // prepare command string
                    string selectString = @"SELECT Status FROM jiahe where [User] = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";

                    // 1. Instantiate a new command with command text only
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(selectString, objConnection);

                    // 2. Set the Connection property
                    cmd.Connection.Open();

                    // 3. Call ExecuteScalar to send command
                    string str = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                    cmd.Connection.Close();

                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input!");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error!");
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
        //MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need datagridview cell content value changed. You should make a string which will be updated each time you edit a row with the ID/index of the selected row. Then you can make an update to the database when the button2 is clicked.

Comment: Can you please show me a rough example of how it should flow?

Comment: take a look here http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database or here http://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/insert-update-delete-with-datagridview-control-in-c-windows-application/